# Given values of X , find fractions

Tags: arithmetic

Solve the equation expressing $x$ in terms of $y$
$$x^2 - 6xy + 5y^2 = 0$$

Given that area of part $A$ of a circle is
$$3x^2 - 2xy - y^2 \text{ cm}^2$$

Area of circle is $4x^2$ cm^2

Calculate fraction $$\frac{\text{Area of part $A$ of the circle}}{\text{Area of circle}}$$

My workings

$ X= 5y OR y $

Sub X=5y 
Area of part A of the circle = $ 3(5y)^2 - 2(5y)(y) - (5Y)^2 = 40 y^2 $

Area of circle = $ 4 (5y)^2 = 100y^2 $

Fraction = $40y^2 / 100y^2 = 2/5 $

I found that my ans is wrong and the ans is 16/25 can anyone help me .. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score -1):

Hint divide first equation by $y^2$ you get a quadratic in $y/x$ thus getting relation between $y,x$. Hope its clear.